# Install4J linux installer fails with "no server JVM at" error unless you use -J-client

Tags: java, linux, jvm, install4j

I have an installer I created a few weeks ago that runs fine on Linux and installs my software perfectly.  I had to reload Install4J and recreate my installer project.  Now the installer that I build fails to run on Linux with an error...

Error: no `server' JVM at`/home/jaz/542/rc2/appxsetup-linux-32.sh.8376.dir/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so'.

I am using the same JRE bundle as before.  I compared the generated installer scripts and noticed that the older installer includes a -client option when running the JRE.  I ran the failing installer with a -J-client option and now it works.

Any idea why Install4J decided to not include that JVM command line option and how to convince it to start adding it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the launcher wizard, go to the "Java invocation->Preferred JVM" step and select the "client" option.

Comment: That did not help.  The problem I am having is with the installer created by Install4J, not the launcher it will eventually install.  Here is what I am seeing when I try to run the generated installer...

[root@devo rc2]# ./appxsetup-linux-32.sh
Unpacking JRE ...
Preparing JRE ...
Starting Installer ...
Error: no `server' JVM at `/home/jaz/542/rc2/appxsetup-linux-32.sh.8778.dir/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so'.

Comment: Did you prepare the JRE bundle yourself? Can you try another JRE bundle?

Comment: I'm using the same JRE bundle I used in the install4j installer I created two weeks ago that does work.  That installer has the this code embedded in it "$INSTALL4J_JAVA_PREFIX "$app_java_home/bin/java" -client -Dinstall4j.jvmDir=..." and the installer I just created that does not work has this "$INSTALL4J_JAVA_PREFIX "$app_java_home/bin/java" -Dinstall4j.jvmDir=..."  The installer itself appears to have been built requesting the -client option two weeks ago and the installer I just built does not.  The installer I used two weeks ago may have been an older version of Install4J 5.

Comment: This is a jre bundle we downloaded from the bundle downloader a while ago.  Linux is no longer a option.

Comment: I have no idea why this happens, but you could add `-client` to the "VM parameters" property of the installer on the Installer->Screens & Actions step

Comment: That fixed it!  Thank you.